# Jsoup query example Android

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to get this text "Huge storm wreaks destruction in Fiji" from http://www.bbc.com/news

Since the DIV class

> pigeon-item__body

is used in the same DIV multiple times, there are no #id`s, nothing special about this text to "catch" it.

I have tried with:

```
div.pigeon-item__body h3
```

But I get back 2 elements...

> 0
>   
>   Cameron calls EU referendum for June
>   1
>   
>   Huge storm wreaks destruction in Fiji

and what if I would have 10 elements there, how to select the 6th element only?

I just need a jsoup selector query example.

Is there some jsoup query generator? I have tried this http://try.jsoup.org but when I don`t know how to make the query this is of very little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selector with your browser - open the page and press F12 to launch the developer tools. I use FireFox, but its quite the same for other browsers too - choose the `Inspector` tool and choose the element picker (FF - left most tool). After that choose the element you want to get and The browser will highlight the code that contains that element.
Place the mouse over the highligthed code, right click it and select `Copy unique selector`. Now you can use that selector for your `Jsoup` code.

Comment: I was cracking my head for 2 days with this selectors.... I even wrote a regex function that extracts some of the data... Thank you! This works.